# php save session (form) doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, session, save

I'm making a website with a form and want to save the inputted data after e new page with the errors was opened.
On the new page you then have a link to the previous one so you can edit it.
The problem is the editing...
I want to save the data using a session but apparently it doesn't work.

I'll post the code partially so you guys don't get bombed. If you need more just ask ;)

In the HTML ocntact form:

```
 <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['your_form']) && !empty($_SESSION['your_form'])) {
    $form_data = $_SESSION['your_form'];
    unset($_SESSION['your_form']);
}
?>
<form id="contactForm" class="doorlopendetekst" name="htmlform" method="post" action="PHP/html_form_send.php">
    <table width="80%">
        <tr>
             <td valign="top" id="td">
              <label for="first_name">Voornaam</label>
             </td>
             <td valign="top">
              <input  type="text" id="roundedborder" name="first_name" placeholder="Voornaam" maxlength="50" size="30">
             </td>
        </tr>
```

In the PHP file to send everything (completely at the top to avoid the 'already sent error'):

```
<?php
session_start();
//assign all posted values to a session
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['your_form'][$key] = $value;
    }
} 
?>
<html><body>
<?php
```

I don't get any errors. It just doesn't save the data.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `value` attribute to the `input field`.

For instance:

```
 <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $form_data['first_name'];?>"
 id="roundedborder" name="first_name" placeholder="Voornaam" maxlength="50" size="30">
```

EDIT 1: (@Terry Harvey 's suggestions)

```
 <input  type="text" value="
 <?php (isset($form_data['first_name'])) ? echo $form_data['first_name'] : echo "" ;?>
 "id="roundedborder" name="first_name" placeholder="Voornaam" maxlength="50" size="30">
```

Comment: i'm getting this when i try it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26009685/Naamloos.png
On the bright side it seems it actually does something now... :)

Comment: You need to save the form's file as `php`.It seems that your server ignores this php code...weird.

Comment: won't that affect the rest of the page?

Comment: You're trying you run php code in an HTML file? Of course it won't work. How your server would know there's php code in their to run?
Basically , PHP files can run HTML , HTML files can't run PHP.

Comment: i saved it as .php but i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /.../public_html/contact.php on line 73

Comment: hahaha :p     <input  type="text" value="<?php (isset($form_data['first_name']) ? echo $form_data['first_name'] : echo "" ;?>" id="roundedborder" name="first_name" placeholder="Voornaam" maxlength="50" size="30">

Comment: think i found it... there is a ')' missing. This will solve it: echo "" );?>". Yes?

Comment: You've right , but you added it in the wrong place:
`(isset($form_data['first_name']))` <-- Here.

Comment: Try the first solution I suggested , before the `edit1` part.

Comment: now i get this at the top of my form: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /.../contact.php:10) in /.../contact.php on line 60

line 60 contains: session_start();

Comment: It's another problem which not related to your original question.
Consider looking for an answer (google , stackoverflow) and after that it will work.

Comment: thx found it :) solved and works just the way i want it now. i'd rep you but i can't because i don't have enough rep myself :s

Answer (score 0):

looks fine, but you need to place the previous values into the html portion of the form:

```
<input .... value="<?php echo $form_data['name']; ?>" .../>
```

Comment: You might want to check if it's set first. :)

Comment: It's about semantics , if it's not set and (usually) error_reporting is not set to show notifications - it will echo nothing.